# point to point SSL connection in python

Tags: python, ssl

Any code example of working point to point SSL communication between a server and clinet written in python.

I am using asynchat.async_chat for communication as of now and I want to make the communication secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a patch for asynccore that enables SSL. Although make sure to read through [the bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue10084) to understand whats going on.

http://bugs.python.org/file20752/asyncore_ssl_v1.patch

Answer (score 2):

Twisted supports SSL fairly well, based on pyOpenSSL/OpenSSL.  The online documentation includes examples of [a client](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/echoclient_ssl.py) and [a server](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/echoserv_ssl.py).  There is also [a howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html) giving explanations of how things work.